# Combinations of distributions to be called with `RandomVariate`

Tags: random, distributions, expression-manipulation

I'd like to manipulate distributions that I'm going to retrieve using `RandomVariate`; e.g., I would like to take

```
X = 100 ExponentialDistribution[2]
Y = NormalDistribution[] + Poisson[3]
```

and have `RandomVariate[X]` be 100 times an exponential RV with parameter 2 and `RandomVariate[Y]` be the sum of a standard real Gaussian and a Poisson with parameter 3; of course, I know that these are not the correct commands but I am wondering what the correct/canonical method/syntax is for these. I can't seem to find anything in the Wolfram documentation which addresses combinations of RVs.

Also, I am wondering how to get the constant distribution (e.g. `Z = ConstantDistribution[10]` has `RandomVariate[Z] == 10` always), I also have not seen this addressed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to use `TransformedDistribution` as in `distX = TransformedDistribution[100 z, z \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[2]]`.

Comment: For the last question, do you seek something like `RandomVariate[DiscreteUniformDistribution[{10, 10}], 100]`?

Comment: Yes, I've also found the hacky `UniformDistribution[{10,10}]` to work, though this feels like it's not the right way to do it. (The answer for `TransformedDistribution` is exactly what I was looking for.)

Comment: You could also use `ProbabilityDistribution[DiracDelta[10 - x], {x, 0, Infinity}]` if `DiscreteUniformDistribution[{10,10}]` does make you uncomfortable. But @MichaelE2 's method is faster and simpler, and I have had issues in the past with how mma treats `DiracDelta`